# Java to JSON polymorphic Serialization of interface implemented by abstract class

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have to serialize Java object into a JSON, but one of the classes attributes has a type which extends abstract class which implement an interface. I'm trying to use jackson in order to save trasparently the sub-type of the attribute but it throws an exception and I don't understed why. What can I do? **Does exist another cleaner/better method to do this?**

that's my abstract class annotation:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,include =JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = SubTypeWhichExtendsAbstract.class, name=BonusToTerritoryTower") })
public abstract class MyAbstrClass implements MyInterface{
```

interface annotation:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(value = ValueBonus.class, name = "ValueBonus") })
public interface MyInterface {
```

error given by Eclipse

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class ...]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

Comment: That is an error that comes out of deserialization.  Jackson will not attempt to create new custom objects during serialization